# Agergar valores a un input dinamico

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola que tal espero que me puedan ayudar, tengo el siguiente problema

tengo este codigo

var ultimoRegistro = arregloTotalVenta[arregloTotalVenta.length - 1]

Este es el resultado de la variable ultimoRegistro, es un array

```
0: {name: 'id', value: '1'}
1: {name: 'cantidad', value: '2'}
2: {name: 'nombreProducto', value: '3'}
3: {name: 'codigoProducto', value: '4'}
4: {name: 'existencia', value: '5'}
5: {name: 'precioUnitario', value: '67'}
6: {name: 'totalProducto', value: '7'}
```

Quisiera que el valor de cada elemento se establezca en cada bloque html, es decir en cada
input poner el valor del elemento 0, en el siguiente input el valor del elemento 1
y asi susesivamente, tengo este bloque for, pero lo que hace es que en los inputs
me pone el valor del elemento 0 en todos los inputs y despues ponen todos los inputs del
elemento 1 y asi sucesivamente, quisiera ver si hay alguna forma de que se pongan sin repetirse algo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
var ultimoRegistro = arregloTotalVenta[arregloTotalVenta.length - 1]
for (var i = 0; i < ultimoRegistro.length; i++) {

   nuevoRegistroProducto += `<div class="row">`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `<div class="col-md-1 mb-3 text-center">`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="id${i}" 
name="id" value="${ultimoRegistro[i].value}" readonly>`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `</div>`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `<div class="col-md-1 mb-3 text-center">`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `<input type="text" class="form-control" 
id="cantidad${i}" name="cantidad" value="${ultimoRegistro[i].value}" readonly>`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `</div>`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `<div class="col-md-3 mb-3 text-center">`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `<input type="text" class="form-control" 
id="nombreProducto${i}" name="nombreProducto" value="${ultimoRegistro[i].value}" 
readonly>`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `</div>`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `<div class="col-md-3 mb-3 text-center">`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `<input type="text" class="form-control" 
id="codigoProducto${i}" name="codigoProducto" value="${ultimoRegistro[i].value}" 
readonly>`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `</div>`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `<div class="col-md-1 mb-3 text-center">`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `<input type="text" class="form-control" 
id="existencia${i}" name="existencia" value="${ultimoRegistro[i].value}" 
readonly>`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `</div>`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `<div class="col-md-1 mb-3 text-center">`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `<input type="text" class="form-control" 
id="precioUnitario${i}" name="precioUnitario" value="${ultimoRegistro[i].value}" 
readonly>`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `</div>`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `<div class="col-md-1 mb-3 text-center">`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `<input type="numeric" class="form-control" 
   id="totalProducto${i}" name="totalProducto" value="${ultimoRegistro[i].value}" 
readonly>`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `</div>`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `<div class="col-md-1 mb-3 text-center">`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `<button type="button" class="btn btn- 
danger">Quitar</button>`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `</div>`;
   nuevoRegistroProducto += `</div>`;

}
```

Comment: En todas las líneas el value es siempre `${ultimoRegistro[i].value}` y creo que por eso se imprime el mismo valor para todos los campos, hasta que `i` pasa al siguiente, se imprime el que sigue, y así.

Comment: Alberto, Por qué no has hecho el [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

No utilices un *loop*. Haz la asignación de valores apoyándote de un contador cuyo valor aumente en uno luego de cada asignación. Algo como esto:

```
let i = 0;

input1.value = array[i].atributo1;
i++;

input2.value = array[i].atributo2;
i++;

input3.value = array[i].atributo3;
i++;

//...

inputN.value = array[i].atributoN;
```